# How can I render a {{}} variable in CKEditor in a Django template?

Tags: django-ckeditor

The variables that I put in Django-ckeditor are not displayed correctly. Is there a way to do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuVlS.jpg)

I used autoescape  and safe .

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ msg }}
{% endautoescape %}

{{ message |safe }}
```